# Determine the parent and thus path of a nested object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

```
var a = {
  b: {
    ab: {
      abc: 1
    }
  }
}

console.log(a.b.ab.abc)
```

The output will be 1.

Is it in any way possible to determine the parents of 'a.b.ab.abc' without previously knowing them?

In otherwords, given `a.b.ab.abc` could one determine the `a` or `a.b` or `a.b.ab`?

Comment: So, do you mean that you've been given `a.b.ab.abc` and you want `a` as result?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by `to determine the parents` and by `without knowing them`?

Comment: If you have object property `a.b.ab.abc`, then you already know that `a`exists, `b` exists,`ab` exists, etc. Do you want to know if `a` has a "parent"?

Comment: Please refer to the definition of the word "question" @IgorSoloydenko in a dictionary, i think you have it wrong.

Comment: "You can't. There is no upwards relationship in JavaScript." from the link posted by @Christian had the answer. This is a shame as is quite limiting.

Comment: @John yeah, sure https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0tRl.png

Comment: That is a title not a question (◔_◔)

Comment: You can look up the parent if you know the property you're looking for - or I should say key.

Comment: Yea i was actually playing around with a state management lib. and it would be extremely helpful to be able to know the path to the parent from a leaf of an object. Thought someone might know if there was something in the pipeline for any of the new javascript tricks coming out in the future.